# Cart/Catalog Price rule for a set of products only

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart, catalog-price-rules

I am trying to set cart price rules for some products if they are together in the cart.

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2

For example:

If product A and B are in the cart I want to make 11 percent for both but not for any other product.

For example:

If Product A and B are in the cart together with product C I want to apply the rule only to Product A and product B but not Product C.

I tried to set two different rules but it did not work, I tried to set one rule for both but then the quantity became an issue, cause I check if the cart has more than 1 products and that means the same product lets say Product A can have 2 as quantity and the rule is being applied on it in this case but I dont want it.

My statement must be like:

If there are more than 1 products and if one of them Is product A and one of the others is Product B set a discount only for Product A and Produt B but not for any other. So not to cart totals but to individual Products that I want to set a discount.

I also tried with catalog price rules but I couldnt get it work even this far.

Any help is appretiated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem in a simple way using Promotion Cart Rules 
I tried it and it works look at this configuration:

[image]

[image]

try to understand my images, use your own products. If you lose just ask .

Comment: Thanks Duarte, I tried a similar approach, did not work exactly as I want but the best so far. Thanks.